# Splitting a sequence and incrementing using Xquery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

I have an xml like below , am trying to convert the xml in to csv

```
<module>
    <content>
        <catalouge SC="25" item="200">
            <Number id="250" RefIds="xyz20000">
                <Character condValue="PRE">
                    <count Number="1" Name="Sree" changeMark="1">FOR A/C 0013, 0047, 0063</count>
                </Character>
                <Character condValue="EMB">
                    <count Number="154" Name="Sree" changeMark="1">FOR A/C 0005-0010, 0021, 0025, 0033</count>
                </Character>
            </Number>
        </catalouge>
        <catalouge SC="180" item="200" >
            <Number id="780" RefIds="xyz20000">
                <Character condValue="EMB">
                    <count Number="1" Name="AB">FOR A/C 0006-0011</count>
                </Character>
                <Character condValue="EMB">
                    <count Number="154" Name="Sree" changeMark="1">FOR A/C 0013</count>
                </Character>
            </Number>
        </catalouge>
        <catalouge SC="567" item="240">
            <Number id="666" Value="123" RefIds="xyz20000">
                <Character condValue="EMB">
                    <count Number="2" Name="SB">FOR A/C 0008-0013</count>
                </Character>
                <Character condValue="PRE">
                    <count Number="1" Name="cherry" changeMark="1">FOR A/C 0018, 0047, 0063</count>
                </Character>
            </Number>
        </catalouge>
        <catalouge SC="8" item="280">
            <Number id="1994" Value="1234" RefIds="xyz20000" >
                <Character condValue="POST">
                    <count Number="3" Name="Sree" changeMark="1">FOR A/C 0006, 0047, 0063, 0090, 0143, 0172</count>
                </Character>
            </Number>
        </catalouge>
    </content>
</module>
```

My xquery is as below

```
for  $p in doc("dar.xml")//module/content/catalouge
            let $SC := $p/string(@SC)
            let $item := $p/string(@item)
            let $isns := $p/Number
            for $isn in $isns
              let $id := $isn/string(@id)
              let $Ref := $isn/string(@RefIds)              
              let $chr := (for $x in $isn return string-join($x//Character//@condValue,", "))
              let $chr_status := contains($chr, 'EMB')
              **let $count :=  $isn/Character/data(count)
              let $count_status :=  contains($chr, '0006')**
              let $Num :=  $isn/Character/count/string(@Number)
              let $sep :=";"
return (if($chr_status and $count_status) 
    then ()
  else(concat($SC,$sep,$item,$sep,$id,$sep,$Ref)) 
)
```

I'm performing an and operation here if both status are true it should print nothing if it is false it should print some value.
My Output should as below:

```
567;240;666;xyz20000
8;280;1994;xyz20000
```

But here my issue is, the data which is present in count tag , has a sequence of values , How can I increment the range tokenize those and search for 0006 which returns a boolean value

```
<count Number="154" Name="Sree" changeMark="1">FOR A/C 0005-0012, 0021, 0025, 0033</count>
```

FOR A/C 0005-0012, 0021, 0025, 0033 which actually mean **0005 to 0012**--> I have sequence 0005,0006,0007,0008,0009,0010,0011,0012,0021, 0025, 0033

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be similar to your previous question, you can use `tokenize` and the `to` operator after removing the `FOR A/C`  prefix:

```
//count 
! 
(. 
|| ': ' 
|| (((
     substring-after(., 'FOR A/C ') ! 
     tokenize(., ', ') ! 
     (let $tokens := tokenize(., '-')!xs:integer(.) 
      return 
          (
              if ($tokens[2]) 
              then ($tokens[1] to $tokens[2]) 
              else $tokens[1])
          ) 
    ! format-integer(., '0001')) = '0006')))
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hwpi2/2 gives

```
FOR A/C 0013, 0047, 0063: false
FOR A/C 0005-0010, 0021, 0025, 0033: true
FOR A/C 0006-0011: true
FOR A/C 0013: false
FOR A/C 0008-0013: false
FOR A/C 0018, 0047, 0063: false
FOR A/C 0006, 0047, 0063, 0090, 0143, 0172: true
```

Comment: Am new to XQuery and stack over flow too, I didn't fully understand your code , but  the output is correct, any URL you would suggest to understand fully please

Comment: Well, there is a least one nice book http://www.datypic.com/books/xquery/ on XQuery, for a cheaper and shorter overview perhaps https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3 and https://www.altova.com/training/xquery3 helps.

Comment: Thank you for the URL's, How to avoid this text from the output "FOR A/C 0013, 0047, 0063: " and yield only true or false

Comment: Well, the text is produced by `. || ': ' ||` so remove that if you don't want it or need it. But perhaps start by reading and working with an XPath and/or XQuery tutorial if you even don't know basic operators.

Answer (score 1):

To tokenize a comma-delimited string and search for a member, returning a boolean in the case of a match:

```
let $string := "0005,0006,0007,0008,0009,0010,0011,0012,0021,0025,0033"
return
    tokenize($string, ",") = "0006"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this pure XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
for $text in 'FOR A/C 0005-0010, 0021, 0025, 0033'
 return
  (for $vTokens in tokenize(substring-after($text, 'FOR A/C '), '\s*,\s*')
    return
      $vTokens = '0006'
      or
       $vTokens[for $part1 in tokenize(.,'-')[1],
                    $part2 in tokenize(.,'-')[2]
                   return
                     $part1 le '0006' and $part2 ge '0006'
                ]
     )[.] and true()
```

This evaluates to `true()` as it should.

**Here is an example with multiple inputs**:

```
for $text in
    ('FOR A/C 0013, 0047, 0063',
     'FOR A/C 0005-0010, 0021, 0025, 0033',
     'FOR A/C 0006-0011',
     'FOR A/C 0013',
     'FOR A/C 0008-0013',
     'FOR A/C 0018, 0047, 0063',
     'FOR A/C 0006, 0047, 0063, 0090, 0143, 0172')
  return
  (for $vTokens in tokenize(substring-after($text, 'FOR A/C '), '\s*,\s*')
    return
      $vTokens = '0006'
      or
       $vTokens[for $part1 in tokenize(.,'-')[1],
                     $part2 in tokenize(.,'-')[2]
                   return
                     $part1 le '0006' and $part2 ge '0006'
                ]
     )[.] and true()
```

**When evaluated, again the correct results are produced**:

```
false true true false false false true
```

Comment: when am running with this for $text in 'FOR A/C 0008,0006,0021, 0025, 0033' it is yielding  false, even though it has 0006 in it

Comment: @Sreekala Yes, because the code assumes the separator is exactly the string ", ".

I will update the answer to be more flexible.

Comment: @Sreekala, I have updated the answer, try to find now anything wrong. If you can't find any further issues, it makes sense to accept the (best) answer  :)